# Back up old time machine backup without mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, backup, time-machine, hfs+

A long while ago, I owned a macbook for several years, and backed it up on to an external hd with time machine.  I no longer have a functioning mac, but I do have the original drive, and the hd.  I've purchased a new hd and am trying to organize my backups (another story but okay).

I would like to make a copy of the time machine backups to another disk.  The backups themselves are ~50GB, but they are on a 1TB partition (with other stuff on it). The new drive is formatted as ntfs.

Things I've considered/tried:

- imaging the partition - too big
- simple `cp -r` - doesn't handle hard links well, resulting copy is 2x as large
- `rsync -qaHAXS` - encounters 'operation not supported' failures, I'm guessing of something to do with copying from an hfs+ to ntfs partition?
- creating an image using brasero - failed because of duplicate file names (seemed like something to do with the way time machine archives file diffs)
- Creating a 50GB image, formatting it as HFS+ with hfsprogs, mounting as loop device, copying with rsync - couldn't get it to work, rsync was failing again so I gave up.
- Using disk utility to create an image, or finder to copy - well, don't have access to a mac right now.

Thoughts?  My only requirements are to a) make a copy I can theoretically restore from if I needed to, and b) not have it be significantly bigger than what I have now..

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be sufficient to just copy the most recent snapshot? This would not be restorable with Time Machine if you ever get a new Mac, but all the files (that hadn't been deleted at that time) would be there. (I suspect most of the errors you're getting e.g. with `rsync` have to do with TM using hard-linked *directories* between different snapshots, while most filesystems only allow hard-linked *files*.)

Comment: I suppose so, but since the backups are so old anyways, this is mostly for the piece of mind.  I don't really remember what was there so I feel like taking the most recent snapshot doesn't cut it..